# How can I have the size of matplotlib heatmap subplots reflect the number of rows in the data for each subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib in python to create heatmaps for different clusters I've created using k-means clustering. Right now I'm able to produce this figure:

[image: Heatmap]

But I want the number of rows in each cluster reflected in the size of the heatmap, instead of them all being scaled to the same size. Is GridSpec the right way to do this? It's the only thing I can find trying to Google the solution, but it seems more suited to situations where you have subplots on a grid and you want a certain subplot to span more than one row or column on the grid. In this situation, I would be creating a grid with thousands of rows and telling each subplot to span hundreds of them. Is this still the best way to do it?

Edit: In case my question isn't clear, I'm ultimately trying to create a figure like this one. Notice how it's easy to see in the left figure that cluster E is larger than cluster F:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridSpec` has an argument `height_ratios`. You can set it to a list of the vertical shape of the heatmaps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.random.rand(n,8) for n in [3,7,10,4]]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(data), 
                         gridspec_kw=dict(height_ratios=[d.shape[0] for d in data]))

for ax, d in zip(axes, data):
    ax.imshow(d)
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]